# Single word for "to quickly find something"

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a single word to say "to quickly do something", namely "to expedite something."

Is there a single or two word expression to convey "to quickly find something", as in to locate, to spot, to ferret out, etc. without an adverb? I'm not getting much luck googling for synonyms of those expressions.

The context is sales copy:

> Our site lets you quickly find the video scenes you like and...

Comment: Any of these: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/discover ?

Comment: to google something? :D

Comment: @mplungjan - I'm afraid not. The context is sales copy: "Our site lets you quickly find the video scenes you like and (...)". I came up and settled with with "to laser in" since posting the question, but leaving this open for now in case someone thinks of something better. :-)

Comment: "quickly find" works for me

Comment: How important is it to you that it be "without an adverb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ruled out adverbs, so the following two suggestions (which I suppose are adverbial phrases) might not be suitable either, but:

“[spot/find/locate]  [in/at a glance](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-a-glance)” could work to imply quickness and/or

“… [in a breeze](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breeze)” could have the added benefit of implying both ease and by extension, speed:

> Our site lets you find/spot/locate the video scenes you like *in a
>   glance/breeze* and...[even more].

Comment: In a breeze -- love it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

From the text of your copy, I would suggest [home in on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/home+in)

> Our site lets you quickly home in on the video scenes you like and...

Synonym: *Zero in on*

Alternative spelling [hone in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hone%20in) - I would consider honing my skills by homing in on a specific subject, so I would not use that version myself

British books:

[image: British]

American books:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possible expression might be **to lock in on something**".

Comment: Never heard that expression

Comment: Perhaps you meant home in on

Comment: @mplungjan - indeed lol. was meant: to lock in on, like a guided missile.

Answer (score 0):

'Search' is best.
Our site lets you search video scenes you like and....

Comment: Mm, no... because it conveys the idea of +searching+, whereas I'm trying to convey the idea of actually *finding fast*. :-)

Comment: How about 'spot', 'stumble on' or 'trackdown'. I guess 'spot' should work.

Comment: Yeah, I considered to spot, but I'd then need the quickly bit to convey the right idea. Still playing with ideas, though... pinpoint, conjure up, or even pin down for that matter... :-)

Comment: Maybe, **Catch**. Of course, I think it's a bit informal.

Comment: Why not simply "get" or "obtain" ? It skips the searching part entirely. "Our site lets you obtain/get instantly the videos you like" ?

Answer (score 0):

How about *discover*?

## Off-topic unsolicited advice *(hehe)*

From a marketing and messaging perspective, you don't need to refer to a "site" since most people will assume that a website is involved. So how about something like:

*Our [advanced] video search-engine lets you **instantly** discover the videos that match your criteria...*

Answer (score 0):

> **identify**
>
> *Verb* (identifies, identifying, identified)
>
> Recognize or distinguish (especially something considered worthy of
>   attention):
>   *a system that ensures that the student’s real needs are identified*
>  <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/de/definition/englisch_usa/identify)</sub>

The sentence would be

> Our site lets you identify video scenes you like and...

Answer (score 0):

promptly picks out the video scenes

Answer (score -1):

'Rummage'(verb) 
It means to search haphazardly.

Comment: But it doesn't necessarily mean _find_. You could rummage for something and never find it, so I'm not sure this suits OP's purposes.